# What ancient prayer contains the term "Osem" (אֹסֶם)?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, words, hebrew

[This site](https://www.tefen.com/insights/services/Strategy/the_story_of_osem__a_nestle_company) claims that *Osem* (אֹסֶם) is *a term taken from an ancient Jewish prayer.* What prayer would that be?

---

<sup>Anectodote: I had assumed it was a Hebrew transcription of the English word *awesome* due to the company's slogan *It's Good. It's Osem.*</sup>

Answer (score 13):

In the Prayer which the *Cohen Gadol* (high priest) said on *Yom kippur* after he exited the קודש הקדשים (Holy of Holies), (Found in the *Machzor* of *Yom-kippur* toward the end of the Avodah prayers], we find the words ""תהא השנה הזאת שנת  **אסם**" May this year be a year of ***Osem*** - abundant produce.

Comment: This prayer as the source is apparently supported by [Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA)

Comment: @ba The footnote says that I was not all wrong, though.

Answer (score 2):

While the more familiar 'Yehi Ratzon' supplication given by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93457/15571) answer is probably the source of the company's name it may be worth noting another usage from antiquity of this precise form.

In a poem to be sung on the eve of RH & YK, [R. Ephraim of Bonn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_of_Bonn), 12th c. wrote ('Piyyute R. Ephraim br' Yaakov M'Buna' p.44):

> שנת אסם וברכה באו אלי כעת מחר לחננה

(Unfortunately, I cannot locate a link online.)

Parenthetically, Ilan Adler ([Leshonenu](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A0%D7%95), 1976 p.76) suggests that, contrary to the vocalization by most dictionaries for the singular as 'uh-sum', the proper form should be 'ah-sum' (either way, it's not 'oh-sem').